# turning a for loop into a dataframe.apply problem

Tags: python, pandas

This is my first ever question on here, so please forgive me if I don't explain it clearly, or overexplain. The task is to turn a for loop that contained 2 if statements in to dataframe.apply instead of the loop. I thought the way of doing it was turning the if statements inside the for loop into a defined function, then calling the function in the .apply line, but can only get so far. Not even sure I am trying to tackle this the right way. can provide original For loop code if necessary. Thanks in advance.

The goal is to import a csv of stock prices, compare the prices in one column to a moving average, which needed to be created, and if > MA, buy, if < MA, sell. Keep track of all buy/sells and determine overall wealth/return at the end. It worked as a for loop: for each x in prices, use the 2 if's, append prices to a list to determine ending wealth. I think I get to the point where I am to call the defined function into the .apply line, and errors out. In my code below there may still be some unnecessary lingering code from the for loop usage, but shouldn't interfere with the .apply attempt, just makes for messy coding until I figure it out.

```
df2 = pd.read_csv("MSFT.csv", index_col=0, parse_dates=True).sort_index(axis=0 ,ascending=True)      #could get yahoo to work but not quandl, so imported the csv file from class

buyPrice = 0
sellPrice = 0
maWealth = 1.0
cash = 1
stock = 0
sma = 200

ma = np.round(df2['AdjClose'].rolling(window=sma, center=False).mean(), 2)   #to create the moving average to compare to
n_days = len(df2['AdjClose'])

closePrices = df2['AdjClose']  #to only work with one column from original csv import

buy_data = []
sell_data = []
trade_price = []
wealth = []

def myiffunc(adjclose):
    if closePrices > ma and cash == 1:    # Buy if stock price > MA & if not bought yet
        buyPrice = closePrices[0+ 1]
        buy_data.append(buyPrice)
        trade_price.append(buyPrice)
        cash = 0
        stock = 1

    if closePrices < ma and stock == 1:     # Sell if stock price < MA and if you have a stock to sell
        sellPrice = closePrices[0+ 1]
        sell_data.append(sellPrice)
        trade_price.append(sellPrice)
        cash = 1
        stock = 0

        wealth.append(1*(sellPrice / buyPrice))

closePrices.apply(myiffunc)
```

Comment: Surely this code doesn't run `if closePrices > ma and ...` would throw? It's unclear what this is supposed to do... Perhaps you could have small example DataFrame (and corresponding expected result)

Answer (score 0):

Checking the [docs for `apply,`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) it seems like you need to use the `index=1` version to process each row at a time, and pass two columns: the moving average and the closing price.

Something like this:

```
df2 = ...
df2['MovingAverage'] = ...

have_shares = False

def my_func(row):
    global have_shares

    if not have_shares and row['AdjClose'] > row['MovingAverage']:
        # buy shares
        have_shares = True
    elif have_shares and row['AdjClose'] < row['MovingAverage']:
        # sell shares
        have_shares = False
```

However, it's worth pointing out that you can do the comparisons using numpy/pandas as well, just storing the results in another column:

```
df2['BuySignal'] = (df2.AdjClose > df2.MovingAverage)
df2['SellSignal'] = (df2.AdjClose < df2.MovingAverage)
```

Then you could `.apply()` a function that made use of the Buy/Sell signal columns.